# Reindexing error message in Product Flat Data

Tags: reindex

I am having the same problem with the error message "cannot initialize the index processor", however that is the only error message I have.  I read some of the answers I do not have very big descriptions for my products, and I only added maybe 5 more attributes to the default set so I do not think that would be too many.   I tried some of the suggestions I have read here, removing files from var/locks but have not been able to fix this problem.
My main question is does this error message affect my website in a bad way or what happens if I just leave it and do nothing?

I am not a programmer so simple answers would help most.

Thank you to all.

Answer (score 1):

Run the reindex via command line, you'll get a verbose error message.

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex ...
```

Replace ... with the index name as necessary, you can get a list of the indexes by running,

```
php shell/indexer.php --info
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however since I am not a programmer, I do not know where or how to run a "reindex" via a command line. Can you tell me in detail?

Comment: I gave you the exact instructions on how to reindex via command line. If you aren't familiar, its best asking your developer or hosting provider to do it for you.